# C# Launch a process and suspend as soon as main module is loaded

Tags: c#

I am trying to launch a process and suspend it as soon as the main module is loaded. Currently I am launching the process suspended and in a loop I am resuming the thread, checking is process.MainModule is not null, and if it is, suspending the thread.

Here's some pseudo code

```
process = LaunchSuspendedProcess;

while(true)
{
process.Resume();

if ((process.MainModule)!=null)
 {
   break;
 }

process.Sleep();
}
```

Is there a more consistent way to do this that doesn't depend on timing?

Comment: What is the TYPE of your "process" variable?...some of those methods are suspect.  You might be looking for [WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: @Idle_Mind - It is pseudo code to give the concept of what I'm currently doing to check if the main module is loaded. I am using WinAPI ResumeThread and SuspendThread to briefly suspend and resume the thread until the main module is fully loaded.

Comment: Does your external process have a main window?

Comment: I don't think there is going to be an elegant way to handle this without a loop.  Just put small `Sleep()` in there and possibly some time calculations for a "timeout"?